# Transactional Message REST API - From?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, triggered-send, send-definition

How to set up From Option for Transactional Messaging via REST API?
It seems that it is set up by default of definition creation.

Nothing is specified in
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/transactional-messaging-get-started.htm

and I can see that the only way to select this field is via the send definition in the UI [https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_send_classification.htm&type=5]

However, for Send definitions created from the API, this is not populated in the UI.

Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer to your question. You would need to have a sender profile and delivery profile defined and using the combination of them you need to create a send classification. If you wish you can use an existing one.Sender profile is where you actually define the From name and From Address.
Marketing Cloud external key of a sending classification defined in Email Studio Administration. Only transactional classifications are permitted.
Name of the field that is used for defining this is "classification".